# Is there any possibility to hide account balance or transaction origination?

Tags: transfer, privacy

Imagine I have A and B

A transfers tokens to B

Is there any possibility to:

- hide A account balance?
- hide A EOS account name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, EOS does not support this kind of functionality directly. However, smart contracts may enable this kind of functionality in the future.

Nothing prevents EOS to adopt Ethereum style privacy transaction smart contracts. For example, [Ethereum has AZTEC](https://btcmanager.com/a-deep-dive-aztec-protocol-providing-privacy-ethereum-network/), that allows ZCash like operations on any tokens.